# The differences between passing React component to another component as a props with and without closing tag

Tags: javascript, reactjs, components, react-props

I am trying to figure out what are the differences between passing a component to another component with and without closing tags in React. Here is the syntax.

```
<div className="App">
    <RegularList list={smallList} comp={SmallList}/>
 </div>
```

and

```
<div className="App">
    <RegularList list={smallList} comp={<SmallList/>}/>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I've created a quick example with both options. You may [check it at stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ts-orv9uz?file=App.tsx&hideDevTools=1)

Basically, it depends on how does the component render the input component;

In this example, since the rendering component is coded as following:

```
function ComponentBase({ c }) {
  return (
    <div>
      <p>Mount: </p>
      {c}
    </div>
  );
}
```

you need to use `comp={<MyComponent/>}` instead of `comp={MyComponent}` ;

---

Note: While there are situations this may be useful (example passing an icon as prop)

```
<Avatar icon={<AvatarIcn />} ... />
```

The example above would use the `children` property instead:

```
function ComponentBase({ children }) {
  return (
    <div>
      <p>Mount: </p>
      {children}
   </div>
  );
}
```